# How to zoom on an UITextView inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which contains instances of an `UIView` subclass.

This `UIView` has a `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer of its layer, and a `UITextView` as a subview.

With zooming enabled on the `UIScrollView`, the `CAShapeLayer` remains sharp when I zoom, but the `UITextView` doesn't.

Is there a way to have the `UITextView` redraw at the correct resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `[yourTextView contentScaleFactor]` or `[yourTextView.layer contentsScale]`. Set it to the current scalefactor.

Comment: Is it supposed to work immediately ? The text view doesn't seem to be affected when I change its contentScaleFactor

Comment: I am sorry my solution seems not to work with `UITextView`. It works fine with a `UILabel`. As the `UITextView` itself is a `UIScrollView` you somehow have to handle the contentScale of its content-views. I have no solution yet, but i will take a look into it.

Comment: A UILabel is enough for what I need in this case. You solution works.